# startx command fails after deleting /tmp folder

Tags: xorg, gertboard

Okay, I have done something strange which prevents my RPi from entering a graphical environment. I was messing around with my Gertboard and was in the process of configuring the ATMEGA 328P microcontroller, and I accidentally deleted the `/tmp` folder on my RPi, and I rebooted it and didn't notice because I was using SSH, but now when I try to start the Arduino IDE I notice my GUI cannot be instantiated.

Neither can I use the startx command, [here](http://pastebin.com/Ne8y4BgY) is the log.

Maybe it was related to me trying to connect to my desktop with SSH via Cygwin, but it also failed when I tried doing that.

What is the cause of this, and what is a solution without re installing the OS?

Comment: You don't mention if you have recreated the /tmp directory.  Lots of software will assume it exists.

Comment: @joan I rebooted and it was there again.

Comment: In that case I can't see that /tmp has anything to do with your problem.  Did you mistakenly delete any other files/directories at the same time?

Comment: @joan No, however I did install the Arduino IDE and I also ran a script to modify my Pi to get ready for my ATMEGA microcontroller.

Comment: I don't know.  The only error is (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).  I use my Pi headless so am at a loss.  I'd just purge and reinstall xserver-xorg and hope for the best.

Comment: @joan I tried that but it just gave me a blackscreen.

Comment: @joan I just remembered that I also updated the firmware of my raspberry pi, it has caused trouble for me twice now. It may be related to this problem.